# Mysql Count : only showing one result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I want to know what is the right query in counting data in a MySQL database.

for example I want to count the data that has a remark of absent. so the result should be.

```
|stud_name    |total_absent|
|John Bandola |13          |
|Jeff Oliveras|10          |
|Wendy Lizardo|5           |
```

etc. etc.

but the problem is, it only shows 1 result which is like this

```
|stud_name    |total_absent|
|John Bandola |13          |
```

here is my query

```
SELECT 
    stud_name, 
    COUNT(remark) as total_absent 
FROM tb_attendance 
WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
    AND subj_code = 'C100' 
    AND description = 'ADBMS' 
    AND remark = 'Absent'
```

Comment: What does the table look like? Also, you're missing `Group By stud_name`

Comment: oh shoot haha how dumb of me XD, I really forgot to put Group by hahaha
thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you need an aggregate result per `stud_name`, you'd need to `group by` that field:

```
SELECT 
    stud_name, 
    COUNT(remark) as total_absent 
FROM tb_attendance 
WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
    AND subj_code = 'C100' 
    AND description = 'ADBMS' 
    AND remark = 'Absent'
GROUP BY `stud_name` -- here
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL GROUP BY clause is used in collaboration with the SELECT statement to arrange identical data into groups.When you talking about collection,

```
SELECT 
    stud_name, 
    COUNT(remark) as total_absent 
FROM tb_attendance 
WHERE instructor_id = 'INST-20131296' 
    AND subj_code = 'C100' 
    AND description = 'ADBMS' 
    AND remark = 'Absent' Group By stud_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) from tb_attendance where remark='Absent'